# Architecture a service on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a UI where I can start machine learning jobs. When a job is requested, a message is added to a PubSub (kafka) and pulled by the service that will run the job.

I have a problem with this service design. I was thinking about creating the main service on Kubernetes that will pull messages from PubSub then this main service would create pods (or rather jobs) to run the actual ML work.

However, I don't know how to make the main service monitor the "worker" jobs it creates. Do I have to do it manually by persisting the ID of the job somewhere and monitoring it? Also how to deal with the "main" service potential failure?

I feel like this is a "classic" use case but I can't find much about how to solve this.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can monitor events that Kubernetes emits when pods are created, destroyed, etc.

Comment: You mentioned that you will be taking the requests for job execution via Kafka, which leads me to assume that you might be dealing with high volume of such requests. I don't think it will be a practical solution to have one job for each received message. You could get the requests served by the spring cloud stream consumer in your main service itself. If my initial assumption about the high volume of requests is incorrect, you can work with Kubernetes operators and watch for kube events and trigger you actions accordingly.